# Python equivalent of Matlab's surfnorm

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I am looking for a Python function that operates similar to Matlab's surfnorm to calculate normal vectors as points a grid.

[Nx,Ny,Nz] = surfnorm(X,Y,Z)

Generating a plot of the surface with the normal vectors shown would be nice but my primary interest is the calculation of the normal vectors at each grid point on the surface.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at `pyvista` for convenient 3-D plotting in Python. It also has functionality for computing surface normals.

Docs: https://docs.pyvista.org/index.html

Surface Normals: https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/01-filter/compute-normals.html

Comment: I am looking into pyvista. However, it appears to be a substantial library with a bit of a learning curve for what I think is a pretty simple task.